# Correct filterOperator for Edm.Int16 data type in UI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

One of the fields in the OData feed I use is `"Edm.Int16"`. I tried to filter the tiles containing the field but cannot find a correct syntax/`filterOperator` for it. I do believe I checked all possible combination from SAP API but no result.

I have no issues with strings filtering. The following code works as expected.

```xml
<TileContainer id="container1" tiles="{
  path: '/myDataSet',
  templateShareable: false,
  filters: [
    {
      path: 'Today',
      operator: 'Contains',
      value1: '1'
    }
  ]
}">
```

This code doesn't work (with quotes around the number and without; with different operators):

```xml
<TileContainer id="container2" tiles="{
  path: '/myDataSet',
  templateShareable: false,
  filters: [
    {
      path: 'Sort',
      operator: 'EQ',
      value1: '0'
    }
  ]
}">
```

Comment: Does filtering with that value in the plain address bar work? e.g.: `https://myservice.svc/myDataSet?$filter=Sort eq 0`.. Any relevant error messages in the browser console?

Comment: No relevant error messages in the Console.The filtering in the address bar doesn't works either. It doesn't show any errors, but it doesn't filter the data either. The field is set to filterable.

Comment: If the field `Sort` is of type `Edm.Int16`, then `value1: 0` should work (without quotes)

Comment: That is very strange... So, it seems that the filterOperator is not the issues maybe. I tried zero without quotes just now. It doesn't change anything. The tile container stays without changes. The errors list in the Console doesn't change either. What potentially can be the issues?

Comment: Well, first you need to make sure that `$filter=Sort eq 0` works at all from browser's address bar. `filterable` is just an annotation which doesn't necessarily mean that the service actually supports filtering by that field